# Message.GetBody(); Serialization Loop

Tags: c#, azure, biztalk, appfabric, servicebus

I have a problem with serializing a message from Windows Azure ServiceBus.

When i Call the "message.GetBody();" method it ends up in some kind of loop which makes my azure-emulator allocate all memory available on the machine.

My code:

```
            Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.BrokeredMessage message;
            while (true)
            {
                // SB is an instance of a class which let me receive a BrokeredMessage through its ReceiveMessage method.
                message = SB.ReceiveMessage("orders");
                if (message == null)
                {
                    break;
                }


                // This ends up allocating lots of memory until the debugger crashes.
                Procurement.TestOrder torder = message.GetBody<Procurement.TestOrder>();
            }
```

The Used Class:

```
[MessageContract(IsWrapped=false)]
public class TestOrder
{
    [MessageBodyMember]
    public int companyId { get; set; }
}
```

I have also tried using the [DataContract] and [DataMember] attributes on the TestOrder-Class.

By the way, the message is a pretty simple XML-File without any namespaces coming from BizTalk into a queue in azure.

There might be some small flaws with this but i dont see any reason for the serializer to get stuck in a loop.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: when things get "Stuck in a loop " it's usually from recurisive calls for example if you are not accessing the Property member correctly.. but from this code you have..it's hard to tell what's going on..

Comment: Yeah, i thougt so too!
But this code is as simple as it gets.
im just trying to serialize one single element and im sure that the element exists in the xml and it only contains the number 1004.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What error do you receive when using `[DataContract]` and `[DataMember]` to attempt to deserialize?  If you just do `Stream s = message.GetBody<Stream>();` what does `s` contain?

If the payload of the string is text/XML as opposed to binary serialized XML you'll probably need to pass in a DataContractSerializer like this:

```
torder = message.GetBody<TestOrder>(new DataContractSerializer(typeof(TestOrder)));
```

Comment: s contains a "Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.BufferedInputStream".
and by payload i guess you mean the ContentType-property on the message?
The ContentType is "application/soap+msbin1".

Comment: sorry for the late answer by the way, i have been away since wednesday!

Comment: Forgot to answer your first question...
I never receive any errors, the problem is that the GetBody function never stops executing and just fills up the ram.
(resulting in an irrelevant error message which just means that the ram is full and the application must close)

Comment: What I meant was, if you call Stream.Read, what are the contents of the byte[](s)?

Comment: Reading to a buffer and printing out the ascii string representation in the immediate window gives me this:
V\vs\vaV\bD?S?N????L??9\n?'??@\nActivityId\rCorrelationId?$6440c44f-2e83-4914-a0c0-fc7dae88ca77\b=http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/09/ServiceModel/Diagnostics?:??????I?B\r+drD\f\0??9sb://servicebusname.servicebus.windows.net/ordersV@Order@\tcompanyId?1004@\aorderId?\a7172471@\fsuppliercode?\b11169315@\torderdate?\n2012-01-10@\vdesireddate?\n2011-06-16@\tordertext@name?companyname@street?

(The whole message was to long so this is a cut down version)

Comment: and obviously...  that isn´t xml.
Im wondering if something is wrong with the sendport-configuration in biztalk?

Comment: Is BizTalk using a TextMessageEncoder or BinaryMessageEncoder?  It looks like a BinaryMessageEncoder was used.  Can you try using TextMessageEncoder with MessageVersion = None in the BizTalk Send Port settings then looking at the content of the stream received in ServiceBus?

Comment: Feel free to contact me directly via "dstucki" or "David.Stucki" at microsoft__dot__com

Comment: Im not really following you here...
I have looked through all the settings on the sendport and can´t find any trace of settings related to encoding.

Answer (score 0):

To make a quick test try to add a Thread.Sleep(10) after the message.GetBody. I had a similar problem with the local Azure emulator, and this simple trick solved it.

Comment: It made no difference.
And btw, this is going to be a critical peace of code so i dont want code which "just works".
I want to have full control!
Thanks for the reply though!

Comment: If it's so critical then I suggest you to use an Async Pattern (more performance) and the topaz building block from EntLib 5 in order to be resilient to transient fault like here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh680946(v=PandP.50).aspx but using ServiceBusTransientErrorDetectionStrategy. It works perfectly.

Comment: Performance is not the issue, i just want to be sure the code works in all cases.
(which im not if i dont know how the code ive written works)